# Sullivan model for classifying spaces

Tags: lie-groups, rational-homotopy-theory

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group (possibly disconnected), and $BG$ be its classifying space. What is the minimal Sullivan model for $BG$?

**Remark**: When $G$ is a connected Lie group, the Sullivan model for $BG$ would be $(H^*(BG, \mathbb{Q}), 0)$.

Any comments or references are welcomed!

Comment: I know very little RHT, so I can't answer your question, but Is $BG$ nilpotent if $G$ is disconnected?

Comment: And another probably useless comment.  If $G$ is compact, $\pi_0(G)$ is a finite group, so $\pi_1(BG)$ is finite.  Does it follow from this that the rationalization of $BG$ is simply connected?

Comment: @JasonDeVito $BG$ is not necessarily nilpotent, since the fundamental group may not be nilpotent. Take for example the product of a connected Lie group with a finite group with is not nilpotent. I am not sure however if the nilpotency of the  fundamental group of $BG$ implies that $BG$ is nilpotent.